# How to serialize the custom object you are sending in JMS template Convert and Send method

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jms

I am using the below mentioned code to publish into a topic. It is of the format convertAndSend(Destination destination, Object message)

```
    Event event;
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, event);
```

My current Event interface is something like this,

```
    public interface Event {

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public AcEventDatafileTransaction getDatafileTransaction();

    public AcEventObjectTransaction getObjectTransaction();

    boolean isDatafileTransaction();

    boolean isObjectTransaction();

    boolean isRdbmsTransaction();

    String getTransactionId();

    }
```

Its implementation is something like this,

```
    public class EventPublisherImpl implements Event {
    private final AcTransactionRecord transactionRecord;
    private final Ac ac;
    private final String[] actualTemplates;
    private final String[] curveTemplates;

    public AcEventPublisherImpl(final Ac ac, 
                                final String[] actualTemplates, 
                                final String[] curveTemplates, 
                                final AcTransactionRecord acTransactionRecord) {
        this.ac = ac;
        this.transactionRecord = acTransactionRecord;
        this.actualTemplates = actualTemplates;
        this.curveTemplates = curveTemplates;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return transactionRecord.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public AcEventDatafileTransaction getDatafileTransaction() {
        if (isDatafileTransaction()) {
          return new AcEventDatafileTransactionPublisherImpl(transactionRecord.getDatafileTransaction());
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public AcEventObjectTransaction getObjectTransaction() {
        if (isObjectTransaction()) {
          return new AcEventObjectTransactionPublisherImpl(ac, actualTemplates, curveTemplates, transactionRecord.getObjectOperations());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDatafileTransaction() {
        return transactionRecord.getType() == AcTransactionRecord.DATAFILE_TRANS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isObjectTransaction() {
        return transactionRecord.getType() == AcTransactionRecord.OBJECT_TRANS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRdbmsTransaction() {      
      return transactionRecord.getType() == AcTransactionRecord.RDBMS_TRANS;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTransactionId() {
        if (transactionRecord != null) {
            return Integer.toString(transactionRecord.getNumber());
        }
        return "";
    }
  }
```

How do I convert it into a serializable form?

My whole objective is to publish Event object into topic. For that I am using convertAndSend method. That method requires an object of a serialized class, which I currently dont have. It is what I am trying to achieve. 
I have looked at examples where a class with few attributes is serialized using message converter https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-framework-jmstemplate-example/

Please suggest a method through code or point to the appropriate example and how that helps me.

Answer (score 4):

> The overloaded methods `convertAndSend()` and `receiveAndConvert()` in JmsTemplate delegate the conversion process to an instance of the `MessageConverter` interface. This interface defines a simple contract to convert between Java objects and JMS messages. The default implementation `SimpleMessageConverter` supports conversion between `String` and `TextMessage`, `byte[]` and `BytesMesssage`, and `java.util.Map` and `MapMessage`.

So, to support custom type we have to create custom converter which implements `MessageConverter` to convert `Event` object to one of supported message type. The simplest solution is to register `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` provided by spring which support converting object to `TextMessage` in form of json.

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

You can take a look how the serialization process is done on the source code in case you want to create your own converter.

To receive the message, the easiest way is to use `@JmsListener` annotation, spring will implicitly convert the message to its java type using the registered converter

```
@Component
public class Receiver {
  @JmsListener(destination = "dest")
  public void receiveMessage(Event event) {
    // do whatever you need with the event
  }
}
```

another way is to use `javax.jms.MessageListener` but you need to manually convert the message yourself.

```
@Component
public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {// we set the converter targetType to text
        try {
            String json = ((TextMessage) message).getText(); // here you have your event object as json string
            Event event = objectMapper.readValue(json, Event.class); // convert back to event object
        }
        catch (JMSException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
    }
}
```

Ref:

- [MappingJackson2MessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java)
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: I am using messagelisteners which receive the message. It gets a Message object in onMessage method. How do I convert it back to the Event type. I am editing my question to further help understand better.

Comment: I have used that but I  am using messagelistener. How do convert it back to Event object when I receive it as a message ?

Comment: @africandrogba I have updated the answer on how to receive the message

Comment: This doesnt work. I cant convert. I have other objects of different class. I think you noticed that.